# How to change cursor of navigation tools in ArcGIS javascript api?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I want to change the cursor symbol for navigation toolbar(zoom in- zoom out- pan ...).
i search and found [the question](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2396&t=280276) about change cursor symbol but i could not use the code.  I dopn't know why its not works for me. Is there any other solutions to change cursor symbol? 
The below code is my project code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="arcgisjs/esri.css">
     <link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://../arcgis_js_api/library/3.13/3.13/esri/css/esri.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://../arcgis_js_api/library/3.13/3.13/init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://../arcgis_js_api/library/3.13/3.13/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://../arcgis_js_api/library/3.13/3.13/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"href=" http://../arcgis_js_api/library/3.13/3.13/dojox/layout/resources/FloatingPane.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://../arcgis_js_api/library/3.13/3.13/dojox/layout/resources/ResizeHandle.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://../arcgis_js_api/library/3.13/3.13/dojox/layout/resources/ExpandoPane.css" />
    <style type="text/css">


        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #borderContainer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>



    <script>

        var map;

        function startup() {
            dojo.require("esri/map");
            dojo.require("esri/dijit/OverviewMap");
            dojo.require("dojo/dom");
            dojo.require("dojo/domReady!");
            dojo.require("esri/dijit/Legend");
            dojo.require("esri/dijit/Scalebar");
            dojo.require("esri/dijit/Popup");
            dojo.require("dijit/form/Button");
            dojo.require("esri/toolbars/navigation");
            dojo.require("dojo/on");
            dojo.require("dijit/Toolbar");
            dojo.require("dojo/parser");
            dojo.require("dijit/registry");
            dojo.require("dijit/layout/TabContainer");
            dojo.require("dojox/layout/ExpandoPane");
            dojo.require("dojox/layout/ExpandoPane");
            dojo.require("dojox/layout/FloatingPane");

            map = new esri.Map("mymap");

            //Takes a URL to a non cached map service.
            var lyr = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/SampleWorldCities/MapServer");

            map.addLayer(lyr);
            overviewmap = new esri.dijit.OverviewMap({ map: map });

            overviewmap.startup();

            legend = new esri.dijit.Legend({ map: map }, "legendDiv");
            legend.startup();
            scalebar = new esri.dijit.Scalebar({ map: map });

            require(["esri/toolbars/navigation", "dojo/on", "dojo/parser", "dijit/registry", "dijit/Toolbar", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/InfoTemplate", "dijit/form/button"],
        function (Navigation, on, parser, registry) {
            parser.parse();
            navToolbar = new Navigation(map);
            on(navToolbar, "onExtentHistoryChange", extentHistoryChangeHandler);

            registry.byId("zoomin").on("click", function () {
                navToolbar.activate(Navigation.ZOOM_IN);
            });

            registry.byId("zoomout").on("click", function () {
                navToolbar.activate(Navigation.ZOOM_OUT);
            });

            registry.byId("zoomfullext").on("click", function () {
                navToolbar.zoomToFullExtent();
            });

            registry.byId("zoomprev").on("click", function () {
                navToolbar.zoomToPrevExtent();
            });

            registry.byId("zoomnext").on("click", function () {
                navToolbar.zoomToNextExtent();
            });

            registry.byId("pan").on("click", function () {
                navToolbar.activate(Navigation.PAN);
            });

            registry.byId("deactivate").on("click", function () {
                navToolbar.deactivate();
            });

            function extentHistoryChangeHandler() {
                registry.byId("zoomprev").disabled = navToolbar.isFirstExtent();
                registry.byId("zoomnext").disabled = navToolbar.isLastExtent();
            }

        });

        };

        dojo.addOnLoad(startup);


    </script>



</head>
<body class="tundra">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'sidebar', gutters:true, liveSplitters:true" id="borderContainer">
        <div  data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ExpandoPane" title="Legend" data-dojo-props="title: 'Legend', maxWidth:225, splitter:true, region:'leading'" style="width: 225px;">
            <div id="legendDiv">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mymap"  data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="splitter:true, region:'center'"></div>


        <div id="top"  data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="splitter:true, region:'top'" style="height:50px;width:100%">


        </div>

    </div>


   <div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/FloatingPane" id="dFloatingPane" 
   title="A floating pane" data-dojo-props="resizable:false, dockable:true, title:'Navigation',closable:false"
   style="position:absolute;top:150px;left:220px;width:110px;height:300px;visibility:visible;">

 <div id="navToolbar" >
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomin"   >Zoom In</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomout" >Zoom Out</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomfullext" >Full Extent</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomprev" >Prev Extent</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomnext" >Next Extent</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="pan" >Pan</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="deactivate" >Deactivate</div>
    </div>

      </div>





    <script>
        require(["dojo/parser"], function (parser) {

            parser.parse();

        });

    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which of those solutions you tried, but you should be able to do this by changing the css. So for your zoomin button putting this in the style tag should work to turn the pointer into a crosshair:

```
<style>
  #zoomin{
    cursor:crosshair;
  }
</style>
```

That works for normal buttons. Sometimes, though you need to override a class that is in an esri stylesheet (http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/esri/css/esri.css, for example). I haven't had luck doing that from the style tag, and had to write a function that runs after the widget is loaded. So, for example, if you wanted to change the pointer of the home button, this would work:

```
homeButton.on("load", function(){
  var hbuttons = document.getElementsByClassName('home');
    for (var i in hbuttons) {
      if (hbuttons[i].className == "home") {
        hbuttons[i].style.cursor = "crosshair";
      }
    }         
})
```

I'm not sure which method you'll have to use for the navigation bar, but hopefully one of them will work.

***EDIT to show image as cursor***

To use an image as a cursor, do the same as above and substitute in this:

```
hbuttons[i].style.cursor = "url('YourCursorImage.jpg'), auto";
```

Or this:

```
cursor:url('YourCursorImage.jpg'), auto;
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to attach an image to zoom in . How can i do it?

Comment: Depending on the container for the element, you could just change the CSS to have something like `ELEMENT {    background-image: url("SOURCE_TO_IMAGE");}`... Judging from this and your other question, it would probably be better just to create your own navigation bar instead of using ESRI's.

Comment: @wetland, Edited to show an image as a cursor.

Comment: @DanJurgella Thanks. when i copy your code in my project and change the class name to home, the navigation tools not work

Comment: @wetland, "home" is the class name of the home button. You need to find the class of the navigation tools. This can help you get the class of the elements you are working with: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp